# PHP - Array not looping through foreach

Tags: php

```
$array = Array(1,2,3);
foreach ($array as $identifier => $values_arr);
{
     echo(123);
}
```

The result is 123 instead of 123123123.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have are actually two different segments of code.

The first:

```
foreach ($array as $identifier => $values_arr);
```

doesn't actually do anything, and is stopped.

And the second:

```
{echo (123);}
```

so the output is `123`

to get into the foreach you will need to remove the semi-colon:

```
foreach ($array as $identifier => $values_arr){
     echo(123);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is an extra colon on the end of the foreach line. The same issue often happens with if/else lines. I am posting this as I could not find the answer via Google search.

Comment: `The same issue often happens with if/else lines.` No it doesn't; being able to construct valid code blocks is pretty trivial.